# why error is not getting disappeared as soon as alphanumeric is identified while using useEffect(), instead after one step?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

An input should be accepting only alphabets and digits, error info `invalid name not alphanumeric` is appearing till both conditions not met. But even after second conditions gets fulfilled, error info remains, it only gets disappear when again some input is getting entered.

I have just started using useEffect() and i know that it gets called after each render. Please help me in rectifying the code where is the issue?
[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-wildflower-dn29qe?file=/src/App.js)

`

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
const SideEffectDependency = ()=> {
    const [entered, setEntered] = useState("")
    const [errors, setErrors] = useState({})


function validator(){
   
     let regForNumOrAlpha=/^([\w\s]+)$/ 
            let regForNumeric=/\d/
            let regForAlpha=/[A-Za-z]/
            let res1=regForNumOrAlpha.test(entered)
            let res2=regForNumeric.test(entered)
            let res3=regForAlpha.test(entered)
          
            if(res1 ==false || res2 ==false ||res3 ==false){
                errors.name="invalid name not alphanumeric"

            } else{
                errors.name="" }

            
   }

   useEffect(validator,[entered])
       


    return (
        <div>
       
            <input id="name" onChange={(event)=> {
                 
                setEntered(event.target.value) 
               
             } }
                 />

            
            {errors.name && <p>{errors.name} </p>}

        </div>
    )
}
export default SideEffectDependency;
```

`

useEffect() is working by calling the validation but not getting how to rectify it.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are not updating the state.

This is what you are doing

```js
 if(res1 ==false || res2 ==false ||res3 ==false){
                errors.name="invalid name not alphanumeric"

            } else{
                errors.name="" }
```

Solution:

```js
  if (res1 == false || res2 == false || res3 == false) {
      setErrors({name:"invalid name not alphanumeric"})
    } else {
     setErrors({name:""})
    }
```

Comment: i got what you did, rendered again using setErrors(), but let me know if I'm wrong - first with any change, Set Entered is rendering and then useEffect is doing the validation, but as you see the error appeared without setError previously when any value gets entered first time, so it has updated the state, why we need to re render again using setError?

Comment: Question is good, if you see, if the condition is true the actual error message will be `''` but it wont appear asap on screen bcz react doesn't know to update the dom as soon as the condition is met.That is why unless you make change in `input` (add / remove value),by which state updates and now it prints the new error value. To overcome this, i have used state for react to update the dom as soon as some condition is met.